# Threads on Multiple VMs accessing a table on single Instance of DB causing low performance and Exceptions occasionally

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, algorithm

Application is hosted on multiple Virtual Machines and DB is on single server. All VMs are pointing to single Instance of DB.

In this architecture, I have a table having very few record. But this table is accessed and updated by threads running on VMs very heavily. This is causing a performance bottleneck and sometimes record level exception. Database level locking does not seem to be best option as it is introducing significant delays in request processing.

Please suggest if there is any other technique to solve this problem.

Comment: You don't suppose the precise nature of the exceptions is pertinent to the question?

Comment: it's much too broad, you need to provide more info about the kind of queries, you do. If you use a persistence framework. How do you know that it is related to the db? Have you profiled your queries to make sure that you don't have slow queries... It is endless

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will share the details shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Few questions first!

- Is your application using connection pooling? If not, please use it. Creating a JDBC connection is expensive!
- Is your application read heavy/write heavy?
- What kind of storage engine are you using in your MySQL tables? InnoDB or MyISAM. If your application is write heavy, please use InnoDB based tables as it uses row level locking and will serve concurrent requests better.

Answer (score 0):

One special case - if you are implementing queues on top of database tables, find a database that has a built-in queue operation and use that, or use a reliable messaging service. Building queues on top of databases is typically not efficient. See e.g. http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/database-as-queue-anti-pattern.html

In general, running transactions on databases is slow because at the end of each transaction the database needs to be sure that enough has been saved out to disk that if the system died right now the changes made by the transaction would be safely preserved. If you don't need this you might find it faster to write a single non-database application that does what the database does but doesn't write anything out to disk, or still does database IO but does the minimum possible. Then instead of all of the VMs talking to the database directly they would all talk to this application.